# Separate site in two domains to optimize SEO

Tags: seo, forum

I have a blog and a forum in the same domain.

The forum has over 300.000 topics with millions of posts.

A fair share of this content could be treated as thin content with lots of pages being around the same keywords.

For example: my blog have a great post about "muscle gain", but in the forum there's, literally, 2000 user-generated pages "targeting" this same keyword.

With the recently core updates, I was thinking that separating the forum from my blog could optimize SEO.

PS: the blog brings the majority of the traffic (not the forum).

Could this be a good idea to prevent penalties now and in the future ? Maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr either use a different subdomain or noindex your forums**

There are actually two questions here, and the answers should guide your decision.

1. Are forum threads 'thin content'?
2. Will forum threads rank higher than my blog entry for [a certain keyword]?

If #1 is true, then #2 is unlikely to happen (unless your blog article somehow contains less information than the threads).

**Does Google consider Forum Threads as Thin Content? Probably**

Two threads (caveat: before 2015) suggest that Google might treat forum discussion threads as thin content.

- [Google Search Console Help: Englishforums.net ht by thin Content Penalty](https://support.google.com/webmasters/forum/AAAA2Jdx3sUT-4i0yB7CrQ?msgid=M7mngz551hgJ)
- [Moz Forums: Are Forums on a Subdomain Thin Content?](https://moz.com/community/q/forum-on-a-sub-domain-thin-content)

Your two options here are either to noindex the entire forum (so Google doesn't see the threads) or move the forum to a subdomain (eg forums.yourwebsite.com). Even so, you might have to noindex the forums if you do get hit by thin content penalty eventually.

But wait, why even keep the threads indexable?

**Discussion threads are great for super long-tail keywords.** 
When someone asks a question in your forum, they're likely to also ask Google that. Your discussion threads have some search value, especially for specific, niche queries.

The two sources I cited came from forums - Moz and Search Console specifically. If any site has great search practices, it's them.

Letting your forums be indexed can bring you long-tail search traffic.

**To mitigate any thin content penalties, put your forums on a subdomain**
And you definitely need to noindex certain pages with duplicate/similar content, such as user profiles, reply forms and so on. Then, as an additional bonus, if you notice a particular thread getting a lot of traffic and activity -- time to write it up as a blogpost.

There is also an unanswered query from here that never got a substantive reply: [Could adding a forum hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86939/could-adding-a-forum-hurt-seo)

Comment: This is a wise strategy. I doubt ALL of the posts are thin content and therefore would only consider going the subdomain + noindex liberally approach. Also, if a "thick" post on the forum happens to be in the question/ answer format, you could then apply Q&A structured data to it and possibly get it a rich result in relevant Google searches: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage